# Incompatible type in mypy seen using **kwargs

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following code:

```py
def _describe_assoc(
    dxgw_id: str,
    vpgw_id: str = ""
) -> DescribeDirectConnectGatewayAssociationsResultTypeDef:

    kwargs = {"directConnectGatewayId": dxgw_id}
    if vpgw_id:
        kwargs["virtualGatewayId"] = vpgw_id

    client: DirectConnectClient = boto3.client("directconnect")
    return client.describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations(**kwargs)
```

When I run mypy I get:

```
error: Argument 1 to "describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations" of "DirectConnectClient" has
incompatible type "**Dict[str, str]"; expected "Optional[int]"
```

I've seen a whole bunch of questions about issues like this here, but in all cases, the answer was to change the function definition. Here, I don't have control of the function definition.

How can I type all of this properly to satisfy mypy?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the error message, but doesn't this have something to do with `describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations`, which isn't described here? You may not control the function definition, but you presumably have some read access to it? You are sending it the `kwargs` dict, which certainly isn't described by the `Optional[int]` type of a *positional* parameter.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Yes, `describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations` comes from Boto3. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/directconnect.html#DirectConnect.Client.describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations Otherwise I do not understand.

Comment: Do you need to use type annotations? Where are you getting the type info for boto3?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe There's a module that publishes the Boto3 types for just this purpose. I guess I don't need to; I want to :)

Comment: So what are the annotations for `describe_…`?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe They are documented in the link I just shared. I am not however sure where the source code is. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you're running into here is that one of the parameters of the function you're calling (`maxResults`) is an `int`.

MyPy knows that your `kwargs` variable just contains strings, and it doesn't know anything more than that. For all it knows your dictionary is mapping `maxResults` to a string.

You can give it a clue by using a `TypedDict` as follows:

```
from typing import TypedDict
    
class GatewayKwargs(TypedDict, total=False):
    directConnectGatewayId: str
    virtualGatewayId: str

def _describe_assoc(
    dxgw_id: str,
    vpgw_id: str = ""
) -> DescribeDirectConnectGatewayAssociationsResultTypeDef:

    kwargs: GatewayKwargs = {"directConnectGatewayId": dxgw_id}
    if vpgw_id:
        kwargs["virtualGatewayId"] = vpgw_id

    client: DirectConnectClient = boto3.client("directconnect")
    return client.describe_direct_connect_gateway_associations(**kwargs)
```

Strictly speaking, TypedDicts aren't foolproof, and the MyPy devs know that it can be tricked into accepting something that it shouldn't using them. But you'd really have to go out of your way to do so, so they'll accept this construction is probably safe.